# jQuery Mobile remove top rounded corners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a DIV which holds an `<ul>` and a `<li>` to get a nice header. Below is a `collapsibleset`. Problem is that it has `ui-corner-all` class. If I remove the class I will no longer have rounded corners on my collapsibleset. Trying to add `ui-corner-bottom` instead but nothing happens.

```
$("#mydiv ul").append(

                "<div data-role='collapsibleset' data-theme='a' data-content-theme='a' style='margin: 0'>"
                +"<div data-role='collapsible'>"
                +"<h3>Section 1</h3>"
                +"<p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>"
                +"</div>"
                +"<div data-role='collapsible'>"
                +"<h3>Section 2</h3>"
                +"<p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>"
                +"</div>"
                +"<div data-role='collapsible' class='ui-last-child'>"
                +"<h3>Section 3</h3>"
                +"<p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>"
                +"</div>"
                +"</div>"
        
        ).trigger("create");
```

`// not working -> //$("#mydiv div").removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-bottom").trigger("create");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

To remove `border-radius` from *collapsibleset*'s top only.

```
.ui-collapsible-set > .ui-collapsible.ui-corner-all {
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

---

Just add `data-corners="false"` to *collapseibleset* div. Also, use `.enhanceWithin()` instead of `.trigger("create")` as it is deprecated in jQM 1.4.

```
$("#mydiv ul").append("<div data-role='collapsibleset' data-theme='a' data-content-theme='a' style='margin: 0' data-corners='false'>"
                +"<div data-role='collapsible'>"
                +"<h3>Section 1</h3>"
                +"<p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>"
                +"</div>"
                +"<div data-role='collapsible'>"
                +"<h3>Section 2</h3>"
                +"<p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>"
                +"</div>"
                +"<div data-role='collapsible' class='ui-last-child'>"
                +"<h3>Section 3</h3>"
                +"<p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>"
                +"</div>"
                +"</div>").enhanceWithin();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bdsv0ubd/)**

Comment: I know about data-corners="false", but I only want to remove the top rounded corners of my collapsibleset :-)

Comment: @BakedInhalf updated :) remove `data-inset="false"` when you apply custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class and add round corners by css:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
```

You can use this tool for code generation: http://border-radius.com/